# Linux Interrupts Concurency

Tags: linux, kernel, interrupt

Are interrupts executed on all processors, or only on one?
For instance, when I type, do all processors handle the interrupt? Or only one of them and the rest carry on with other taks?

Comment: Just one processor is interrupted. This is defined by hardware, not by the OS.

Comment: so if I have 8 cores, can I process keyboard, network, IO, mouse, etc. - interrupts at the same time?

Comment: You *could be* processing at most 8 interrupts at the same time; barring restrictions about critical sections inside interrupt handlers, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a high-level view of the low-level processing. I'm describing a simple typical architecture, real architectures can be more complex or differ in ways that don't matter at this level of detail.

When an interrupt occurs, the processor looks if interrupts are masked. If they are, nothing happens until they are unmasked. When interrupts become unmasked, if there are any pending interrupts, the processor picks one.

Then the processor executes the interrupt by branching to a particular address in memory. The code at that address is called the interrupt handler. When the processor branches there, it masks interrupts (so the interrupt handler has exclusive control) and saves the contents of some registers in some place (typically other registers).

The interrupt handler does what it must do, typically by communicating with the peripheral that triggered the interrupt to send or receive data. If the interrupt was raised by the timer, the handler might trigger the OS scheduler, to switch to a different thread. When the handler finishes executing, it executes a special return-from-interrupt instruction that restores the saved registers and unmasks interrupts.

The interrupt handler must run quickly, because it's preventing any other interrupt from running. In the Linux kernel, interrupt processing is divided in two parts:

The “top half” is the interrupt handler. It does the minimum necessary, typically communicate with the hardware and set a flag somewhere in kernel memory.
The “bottom half” does any other necessary processing, for example copying data into process memory, updating kernel data structures, etc. It can take its time and even block waiting for some other part of the system since it runs with interrupts enabled.

Comment: very informative, but this is not an answer to what was asked.